# php word Documents->saveas +encode +read-only

Tags: php

I use this php script to open an array of word files and save them as text.  It works fine, except that in some files, MS Word displays a dialogue box asking to confirm the requred "**encoding**" OR asking if to "open the file as **READ-ONLY**"   This is inconvenient because the script then hangs until I restart it manually.

My question is what should I add to the script below to "tell" MS Word:-

a.  to save it with Windows default encoding  (this option is already checked, and one would only need to press the OK button.)

b. to open the file as READ-ONLY

My script is like ths:-

```
$word = new COM("word.application");
$word->Visible =false;
$doc = $word->Documents->Open($file);
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs(filename,2);  // NOTE: 2 is to save file as text
$doc = $word->Documents->Close(); 
$word->Quit();
$word->Release();
$word = null;
```

On their website, Microsoft  mentions this:-

**ReadOnly Recommended**

true to have Microsoft Office Word suggest read-only status whenever the document is opened. The default is false.

**Encoding**

MsoEncoding. The code page, or character set, to use for documents saved as encoded text files. The default is the system code page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveas%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Your help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: a word .doc/.docx doesn't have an "encoding". are you trying to open html files that have been renamed to .doc? If so, then they're not really word files, and word is properly asking you how to deal with that.

Comment: when saving doc / docx as text (.txt) it asks for the required encoding - sometimes. Thanks

Comment: really I'd like to know what should be added to this line:
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs(filename,2);

Comment: ah, I see. you're converting a .doc to .text, then yeah... it's going to ask for encoding because it needs to know that so it can properly save "special" chars.

Comment: at the top of the page (see msdn link above) it gives the syntax for both C + VB.  How can it be done in PHP COM though?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem is solved by adding this line to the script:-

$word->DisplayAlerts=FALSE;

As explained in my question before, the problem arises because of dialogue menus.
The DisplayAlerts = False  takes care of that.

Regards